# Git: unable to add a directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to add a new directory to a project, but I am not able to do that.

If I do `git status` the new directory does not show.

If do `git add -A` nothing happens, when I do `git status` the directly does not show.

There is not `gitignore` (that I can find at least...)

There is an `exclude` file that contains:

```
Foo.Mobile\platforms\android\assets
Foo.Mobile/platforms/android/.idea/workspace.xml
```

But I don't think that is the problem. The directory I have created is inside:

`C:\Users\Bar\git\FooAndroid\Foo.Mobile\platforms`

And there is a `sparse-checkout` file that contains

```
Foo.Mobile/platforms/android/*
```

And again I don't think that is the problem.

The project is IntelliJ based.

Thanks

Comment: try `git add .`  and then do `git status`

Comment: Did any of the answers (or comments) solve your problem, or at least helpful in tracking it down?  I see some of the answers are up-voted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not provide for working with empty directories or files.
Try creating a dummy file in the directory.

The reason for this is that Git works only on changes in files and if there is no text it can not compare anything.

A diff file also contains the location (directory) to the file and thus automatically adds the directory.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) is a solution if you really want to keep an empty directory in Git.

Comment: Thanks Genkus, the directory is not empty :-((((

Comment: Are the other files/directories in the intelliJ android project added to Git without problems?

Comment: Git add --all will work from any directory in the hierarchy

Comment: @Genkus no Genkus, some do not get added like `/gen`/ or `/out`(but I don't care about those)

Comment: Try 'git check-ignore -v <your_dir>'. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, you must ensure that there is a file in the directory you're adding, since git only operates on files.  Since you've already done this, the next thing to do is to trouble-shoot.

Using `git add .` will only add from the current directory downward; if used, it must be from the root of the repository.  Sometimes, `git add --all` will be easier and more appropriate.

You need to look for a `.gitignore` file.  Notice there is a "dot" at the beginning of the file; on most operating systems (and certainly Windows), these files are classified as "system" files and are hidden by default; you can, however, make them visible in an operating-system-dependent manner.  The .gitignore should be at the root level of the repository you cloned, but sometimes there may be more than one in different directories.  Using a command-line or GUI tool may help find any `.gitignore` files that may exist.

If you're looking at a `.gitignore` file, be sure that you understand any regular expressions which may be inadvertently matching the file you're trying to add.  You could, as a simple test, try renaming the `.gitignore` and trying the add again, but be ready to unstage the files that will be added as a result.  You could also try `git check-ignore -v <dirname>`, or read the help for check-ignore for more advanced options.  Some useful help on this is offered by `git help gitignore`.

If all else fails, try adding an arbitrary test file, to ensure that something else is not wrong with the repository.